# Find string matching id using JQuery

Tags: jquery, string, find, matching

I want to use JQuery to find the last part of this id

I tried this:

```
<input id="test-id-1234">

var f_id = $( 'input[ @id ^= 'test-id-' ]' );
alert(f_id[0].id);
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/r9o8g1cr/

Comment: Ok that's it exactly what i want  but it returns me an error such i said to @nevermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
var full_id = $("input[id ^='test-id-']"); // get the full ID
var res = full_id[0].id.split("-"); // split it on "-"
var yourId = res[2]; // last part is your ID
alert (yourId); // shout it out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var f_id = $("input[id ^='test-id-']");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1kb758zx/

Comment: Ok Nice but when i put this on my code it returns me an error`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`